# Java mapping data from two arrays and insert into third array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am having difficulty mapping the data in two lists into a third list. My sample data is as follows:

```
Categorylist ID:  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,42,46,49,50
CurrentMonthByCat ID: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,42,49,50
(the transaction amount value for CurrentMonthByCat: 92,46,40,180,60,10,1510,200,500,10,234,12)
```

There is a missing 46 in the currentMonthByCat. I am trying to do it in a way such that if the currentMonthByCat ID does not exist from the categorylist ID, I will insert 0 into the third list rather than getting the transaction amount from CurrentMonthByCat and push it into the third list.

```
ArrayList<Double> total = new ArrayList<Double>();

    for(int i = 0; i < categorylist.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < currentMonthByCat.size(); j++){
            if(categorylist.get(i).getCategoryID().equals(currentMonthByCat.get(j).getCategory().getCategoryID())){
                Log.d("IIIII", categorylist.get(i).getCategoryID());
                Log.d("JJJJJ", currentMonthByCat.get(j).getCategory().getCategoryID());
                total.add((double)currentMonthByCat.get(j).getTransactionAmt());
            }else{
                total.add(0.0);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < total.size(); k++){
        Log.d("KKKKK", String.valueOf(total.get(k)));
    }
```

But the printed out result of total list is:

```
  92,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,46,0,0,0...
```

What I expected is:

```
  92,46,40,180,60,10,1510,200,500,10,0,234,12
```

I wanted to insert 0 only if the ID in currentMonthByCat does not match the ID in categorylist. For instance, the ID 46 which is the 3rd position from the right.

I realized the reason is because firstly I inserted 92 into third array, then the categorylist ID is still at 1, then it will compare with all the rest in the currentMonthByCat before moving to ID 2. That is why the unnecessary zeros. But I not sure how to actually sort it to achieve what I wanted.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy one. you can't take a decision of adding zero or value in the total array unless the inner loop finish. so probably you add element existAtIndex and initialize it with -1 and in the loop if you find the element then assign the index to  existAtIndex and break the loop or if it's not exist then you add zero. so the code will be something like :

```
ArrayList<Double> total = new ArrayList<Double>();
int existAtIndex;
    for(int i = 0; i < categorylist.size(); i++){
        // search for the element index
        existAtIndex = -1;
        for(int j = 0; j < currentMonthByCat.size(); j++){
            if(categorylist.get(i).getCategoryID().equals(currentMonthByCat.get(j).getCategory().getCategoryID())){

                existAtIndex = j;
                break;
            }
        }

        // add the value in the element index or add zero if the element not exist
        if (existAtIndex != -1) {
          total.add((double)currentMonthByCat.get(existAtIndex).getTransactionAmt());
        }
        else {
            total.add(0.0);
        }
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < total.size(); k++){
        Log.d(String.valueOf(total.get(k)));
    }
```

For better code you could use contains method to check for the item if exist or not in arrayList instead of using the basic loop. Good luck

Comment: But with this piece of code right, my third last position which is ID 46 and it does not exist in the currentMonthByCat, it inserted the value before that position which is 2 into the third array rather than 0. I think you forget to set the existAtIndex to -1 inside the else for for loop

Comment: I think it's  going to insert zero as it desire. the if condition after the loop means add the position of the element if it's exist or add zero

Comment: I think you got to set the existAtIndex to -1 under the first if statement if it is not equal. I set it and it has achieved what I wanted. Otherwise, it will take the previous value and set it which I have no idea why. Thanks for the helps! :)

Comment: yes, you have to reset the index that's right. I haven't test the code :(

Answer (score 0):

Put your values into `Map<Integer, Double>`

```
Map<Integer, Double> map = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
for (int i = 0; i < currentMonthByCat.size(); ++i) {
    //... categoryId = currentMonthByCat.get(i).categoryId
    //... amount = currentMonthByCat.get(i).amount
    map.put(categoryId, amount);
}
```

Then traverse the map using values from Categorylist ID:

```
// create result arraylist
ArrayList<Double> total = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (int i = 0; i < categorylist.size(); ++i) {
    Double amount = map.get(categorylist.get(i));
    if (amount == null) {
        total.add(0.0);
    } else {
        total.add(amount);
    }
}
```

The result list `total` will contain amounts for existing mappings, or zeros for non-existent.

**Other way**
If it is guaranteed categorylist is sorted and CurrentMonthByCat is sorted

you can then traverse one of the lists while keeping index/cursor to the other list and not iterating the other list from the beginning, but from previously remembered cursor value, resulting in better average performance than n^2

Comment: I initialize the map as such Map<String, Double> map = null; and I got an cannot refer to null object reference error message

Comment: @EmmaHannah edited, added initialization of the map.

Comment: Thanks for the helps! But somehow it set the total to all zero which I have no idea why is it so.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of code for what you are trying to do here. I think the following snippet does what you want in a very readable and maintainable way.

```
    //First of all we are interested in getting a transaction amount for each value in currentMonthByCat
    //so loop around using your object (not sure what it's called)
    for(CurrentMonth value : currentMonthByCat){
        //check if it's present. 
        //We create a new method here that gets you your category list as a list of integers. 
        //This is key to making the whole method much more readable.
        if(categorylist.getIdsAsList().contains(value.getCategory().getCategoryID())){
            //it is so add it
            total.add(value.getTransactionAmt());
        } else {
            //it's not so add a 0
            total.add(0.0);
        }
    }
```

The getIdsAsList method could look like this:

```
public List<Integer> getIdsAsList(){
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (CategoryListItem item : categorylist) {
        result.add(item.getCategoryId());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helps!